# Excel 2013 VBA script needed for

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013, vbscript, text-formatting, visual-basic

I have several cells that have a string of text that are partially Bold and partially NotBold. I need to delete the Bold portion of the Text in the Cells

Example:

[image: ExcelImage]

**lname1, fname1**email1@email.com

**lname2, fname2**email2@email.com

**lname3, fname3**email3@email.com

I would like to delete the Bold "lname, fname" and just keep the email address in the cell.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've tried the Find and Replace and it will find Bold text but when I hit Replace, it replaces the whole cell including the Non Bold text. I do not know of any function in Excel that can format or edit partial text in a single cell. Then again, I am only Intermediate as best with Excel.

Comment: So I guess my question is "How do I delete the Bold portion of the text string in each cell"?
Before: lname1, fname1email1@email.com
After: email1@email.com

Comment: You can check if text is bold with `Range("A1").Characters(i, 1).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"` source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209572/vba-check-if-partial-bolding-in-cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before:

[image]

The code:

```
Sub BoldKiller()
    Dim L As Long, r As Range, t As String, i As Long

    For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection)
        t = r.Text
        If t <> "" Then
            L = Len(t)
            For i = L To 1 Step -1
                If r.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True Then
                    r.Characters(i, 1).Delete
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

and after:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

This macro extracts the bold characters and places them in the adjacent column:

```
Sub BoldKiller2()
    Dim L As Long, r As Range, t As String, i As Long
    Dim rr As Range

    For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection)
        t = r.Text
        If t <> "" Then
            Set rr = r.Offset(0, 1)
            rr.Font.Bold = True
            L = Len(t)
            For i = L To 1 Step -1
                If r.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True Then
                    rr.Value = r.Characters(i, 1).Text & rr.Value
                    r.Characters(i, 1).Delete
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: Gary's Student, BoldKiller will come in very handy. I am hoping you can give me another solution. Same Data from above but this time can we split the Bold Text out and place it in the adjacent column? So, we would have lname, fname in one column and the email address in the net column.

Comment: @Rob808  I will take a look tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you very much. I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: @Rob808  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: EDIT#1 works perfectly. Thank you so much.